# Kentico.Kontent.Management The type or namespace name 'AssetIdentifier' could not be found

Tags: kentico-kontent, kontent-ai

I have generated a model with Kentico.Kontent.ModelGenerator 6.0.1:

```c#
public partial class Car
{
        [JsonProperty("about_image")]
        public IEnumerable<AssetIdentifier> AboutImage { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("about_text")]
        public string AboutText { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("additional_header_image")]
}
```

while compiling getting ERROR :

> Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'AssetIdentifier' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

PS: I'm using the latest Kentico.Kontent.Management 3.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a major release of Genereators SDK. You can try regenerating your models with the latest version.

- https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-generators-net/releases/tag/7.0.0
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentico.Kontent.ModelGenerator

Comment: Thank you @Sevitas ! I used latest beta version of code generator. It is generationg properly models for Management Api 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `AssetIdentifier` [has been removed](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-management-sdk-net/commit/5cefbff0c167076165b2abe397cb899bcbc1350c) and the code generator has not been updated yet.

As a workaround, it might be possible to manually replace the occurrences with `Kentico.Kontent.Management.Models.Shared.Reference`.

I recommend [filing an issue](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-generators-net/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) against the [kontent-generators-net repo](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-generators-net).

Answer (score 0):

The generator adapted for the new major version of the .NET SDK (3.0.0) is currently in beta - Can you try to regenerate models using `7.0.0-beta4` version?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentico.Kontent.ModelGenerator/7.0.0-beta4

There are still two PRs in the queue before releasing the final version:

- https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-generators-net/pull/147
- https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-generators-net/pull/146